# iServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'addVersionedApiExplorer'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, nswag

In an Asp.Net Core v3.1 api, Swagger v3.0, the Swagger UI cannot load API definitions when I have declared multiple versions.

Edit: Also from NuGet:

Mcrosoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning v4.1.1

NSwag.AspNetCore v13.7.0

[Following the documentation of NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCore-Middleware#use-api-versioning) I realized that I have to add the following to my '''Startup.ConfigureServices()''':

```
services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
})
.AddMvcCore()
.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});
```

But '''AddVersionedApiExplore()''' is not available there... then I found [this ApiExplorerOptions wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Explorer-Options) where it states (I understood so) that since Asp.Net Core 3.0 the usage it is:

```
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer( options => { /* configure options */ } );
```

But I endup with the error `'IServiceCollection'` does not contain a definition for `'AddVersionedApiExplorer'`

BTW, all the paths of the service run fine from Postman for each version, the swagger's page loads and shows both of versions I declared but it cannot load their definitions.

Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 39):

Starting from `.Net 6`, the package is now called `Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer`.

the same package uses different implementation in `.Net 7`.

Using the new minimal method of building an app:

```cs
var apiVersioningBuilder = builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    // Use whatever reader you want
    options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader(),
                                    new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"),
                                    new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
}); // Nuget Package: Asp.Versioning.Mvc

apiVersioningBuilder.AddApiExplorer(options =>
{
    // add the versioned api explorer, which also adds IApiVersionDescriptionProvider service
    // note: the specified format code will format the version as "'v'major[.minor][-status]"
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

    // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
    // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
}); // Nuget Package: Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer
```

Answer (score 13):

Solution: AddVersionedApiExplore lives in [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer/4.1.1?_src=template) NuGet package.

Comment: Lupa, just wanted to add a note here. forgetting to include a nuget package - when you are using said package in your project is not exactly a error is it? Thats like going to the movie theatre and realizing that you forgot to bring the ticket. just some food for thought :)

Comment: Thanks @Jay, my fault was trusting in ```NuGetRecommender``` extension. I spent several hours and when I typed services.AddVersionedApiExplorer() it did not suggest to install any package as it did in other similar situations. Sorry by that :/

Comment: ah, i see. now i have the full picture of how you ended up in this situation.

Comment: This package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExploreris deprecated since yesterday. Just use the answer of @Adnan...